# Which is the real reason for why we don't see light interference patterns?

Tags: optics, waves, visible-light, interference, vision

There are many questions like mine in the web, but think I cannot fully understand it.

Let's look at [this question](https://www.quora.com/Why-dont-we-see-interference-of-light-waves-in-common-life). The first answer states that we cannot see light interference patterns because most of the light sources are incoherent. And, this implies that, if observed with a rough time scale (microseconds) the interference pattern disappear. This is shown in the following pictures.

[image][image]

Now, I've at least two three about this answer:

1. Is it saying that if I use an extremely good coherent laser, could I see interference patterns
   (for instance by using two of them)?
2. Is it saying that our nervous system perform a time average with microsecond scale?
3. Why is the non-coherence the cause of our non-seeing the interference pattern? Let's consider
   a couple of pure ideal coherent sources, for instance green at 550nm. I think we cannot see
   their interference pattern because the shadow-light zones are too close to be seen by our eye.
   What does that have to do with coherence?

Comment: You don't need a particularly good laser to see interference patterns. I'm a little unclear about just what you are asking about here.

Comment: see this MIT demonstration of two laser beam interference

Comment: A free and easy experiment for ordinary light diffraction patterns: go into a very dark room, turn on your cel phone flash light, and completely cover the light with your fingers, pointing the light towards a nearby wall. Adjust your fingers so that a tiny slit appears between them just over the light. After a little trial and error, you will get regularly spaced diffraction fringes projected on the wall from the thin slit aperture.

Comment: Example 2 photons can emitted out of phase (net zero E and M), both photons will come to your eye and be detected as individual quanta.   Energy is conserved.

Comment: Consider Feynman path integral ... every photon travels its own path, if the path is not ideal (per Feynman path integral) it is not travelled. Areas of non-travel are dark, all the photons go to the bright areas. The word 'interference" is out of date and historical and it violates conservation of energy! Photons never cancel, they are only emitted and eventually absorbed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If the pattern moves (so that bright regions become dark, and dark become bright) on a timescale small compared to human eye response time, then we won't see the interference pattern (it will be averaged out).
2. If the distance between dark and light region is too small for our eyesight to resolve, then we won't see the interference pattern.

If either or both of (1) and (2) occur, we don't see the pattern. In practice you can get (1) alone, or (2) alone, or both together.

With an ordinary light source (not a laser) you can see interference of the type coming about by partial reflection from a pair of close surfaces. This contributes to the colourful patterns you can see on a film of oil, for example.

With a diffraction grating you can easily see the first (and higher) order diffraction beam, which is owing to interference. You can see this sort of thing in light reflected off a CD (compact disc).

Finally, if you want to interfere light coming from two entirely different sources then here, yes, you do need very special sources such as lasers, and indeed most lasers will not have a sufficiently well-defined frequency for it to work. Their frequency varies with time enough to wash the fringes out on a timescale of microseconds (or faster). But with very narrow-band lasers and a stable set-up you can get the fringes to stay still enough for human vision.

Comment: Consider Feynman path integral ... every photon travels its own path, if the path is not ideal (per Feynman path integral) it is not travelled. Areas of non-travel are dark, all the photons go to the bright areas. The word 'interference" is out of date and historical and it violates conservation of energy! Photons never cancel, they are only emitted and eventually absorbed.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of an interference effect that can be elicited with daylight. This optical phenomenon is called '[Newton's rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_rings)'.

(I'm not going to describe the Newton's rings setup here, please do read the wikipedia article.)

Newton's rings are more defined when using monochromatic light, but using monochromatic light is not a necessity.

A Newton's rings setup that uses white light as source of light will show chromatic effects. When using white light: only the innermost rings will be clearly discernable, further to the periphery the colors are overlapping a lot, making the interference pattern less defined.

More generally, for any setup where the purpose is to elicit interference effects: avoiding chromatic effects by using (close to) monochromatic light is ever so convenient. The closer to monochromatic, the better.

A [Sodium lamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium-vapor_lamp) is quite close to monochromatic, hence a Sodium lamp is a good light source for a double slit setup.

As we know, laser light is well suited to interference experiments. So much so that nowadays *any* demonstration of interference effects is done with laser light.

This tends to give the impression that an interference pattern can be obtained *only* if the source of the light is a laser. That supposition is incorrect; in most setups the property that makes laser light well suited is that laser light is *close to monochromatic*. Just as with Newton's rings, with a (close to) monochromatic source of light chromatic effects in the interference pattern are small.

Another crucial feature is the fact that with most laser devices used in demonstrations the point of emission of the laser light is effectively a *point source*. With a *point source* there is no variability in the distance from the point of emission to the features of the optical setup (for instance a double slit setup). When there is no room for variability in the distance that the light traverses the light is described as 'spatially coherent'.

(Laser light has additional convenient properties, I won't get into those here.)

**Thin film interference**

Let me discuss now another interference effect, again one that occurs with plain daylight: [thin film interference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin-film_interference).

If a little bit of oil is spilled onto a puddle of water the oil spreads out to a thin film. When the thickness of the oil film is down to about the wavelength of visible light we see color effects. (Again: do see the wikipedia article.)

So: the daylight is coming from all directions. That is: the source of light does not have any coherency property. But we see interference effect anyway.

The necessary condition for interference effect to occur is the presence of a specific *phase relation*.

In the case of thin film interference: light can reflect both at the air-oil boundary, or at the oil-water boundary just beneath it. So there are two possible paths, and these two paths give rise to a specifice *phase relation*.

In and of itself light does not have a specific phase, but for light that has the opportunity to travel along two possible paths it is possible to be in a specific phase *relation*.

(Of course, it sounds odd to state that light does not have a specific phase, yet can be in a specific *phase relation*. One way to think of that is to see it in analogy with relativity of velocity. We have the principle of relativity of inertial motion. A single object does not have an intrinsic velocity, but when you have *two* objects then the relative velocity between the two of them is physically meaningful.)

In the case of thin film interference: there is extremely little "wriggle room" for the light. The thin film itself is where it happens. In effect the setup is as small as the wavelength of visible light. The thin film illuminated with plain daylight elicits interference effect. The point is: the setup is so *confined* that for the light source there is no coherency requirement altogether.

With a larger setup the requirements for the source of the light go up.

In order to obtain interference effect: the more "wriggle room" the light has in a given setup, the more stringent the coherency requirements of the light source. That is why it is so convenient to use laser light for interference effect setups. The higher the coherency performance of a light source, the lesser the precision constraints for the setup.

See also:
The youtube channel Huygens Optics, video about the [double slit experiment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h53PCmEMAGo)

While in other youtube video you see a presenter talking, with an animation in the background, in the Huygens Optics video the creator has used his optics equipment (he's an optics consultant with a workshop of his own) to create an actual physical setup, so that he can try various things and see how that affects the result.

Comment: Thanks for all the examples you have provided. Now I've a basic question: why can we see the interference pattern in case of thin film interference and Newton rings, provided that the human eye resolving power is about 0.1?? Are, in this phenomena, colour interference franges more spaced than in other phenomena?